# Not able to update the user-defined variable value in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have defined one variable in Jmeter with some default value. I want to update the value of this variable based on certain conditions. I am using bean shell processor to update the value of this variable.
So the scenario which I am trying is, I am executing my test plan for some fixed number of times(say 2 minutes), and I am also counting(using counter) the number of request jmeter is making to the endpoint. So based on the one specific counter's value, I want to update the value of this user-defined variable. So to update this, I am using below line in bean shell processor -

```
vars.put("variableName","value");
```

So the above statement is only changing the value of the variable for that specific count, after that, it is again referring to previous value. Like,

```
  if(count==100){
vars.put("variableName","newvalue");
}
```

So it is updating this value only at the 100th request, and when 101th request comes up, it again having the previous value.

Can someone guide me on, how can I update this value for the variable. Also I am using one thread group with 10 threads.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue, refer the test plan below for demo:

[image]

So I would recommend double-checking your `if(count==100)` condition, JMeter Variables are normally being stored as [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) so my expectation is that the condition should be amended to look like:

```
if (vars.get("count").equals("100"))
```

Also [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) so consider migrating on next available opportunity.